# parallel 2D convolution using openMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm attempting to implement 2D convolution in C. I have 2 implementations: first one is sequential and the second one is a parallel implementation using openMP.
The problem is that the runtime for parallel code is always more than the runtime for the sequential code. The original algorithm was implemented in C++ using std::vector and It works fine, but I'm trying to implement It in C using pointers and dynamic memory allocation.

Here's the steps taken in the algorithm:

1- read input_matrix and kernel from separate files.

2- compute convolution

3- write the result to a file.

I use dynamic memory allocation for the input_matrix, kernel, and output_matrix. Border columns and border rows are assumed to be neighbors, and kernels are assumed to have odd number of rows and columns.

Here's the sequential convolution:

```
int index1, index2, a, b;

    for(int z = 0; z<rows*columns;++z)
        *(output_matrix + z) = 0;

    clock_t begin = clock();

    for(int x=0;x<rows;++x){
        for(int y=0;y<columns;++y){
            for(int i=0;i<krows;++i){
                for(int j=0;j<kcolumns;++j){
                    a=x+i-krows/2;  
                    b=y+j-kcolumns/2;                   
                    if(a<0)
                        index1=rows+a;
                    else if(a>rows-1)
                        index1=a-rows;
                    else 
                        index1=a;

                    if(b<0)
                        index2=columns+b;
                    else if(b>columns-1)
                        index2=b-columns;
                    else 
                        index2=b;

                    output_matrix[x*columns+y]+=input_matrix[index1*columns+index2]*kernel_matrix[i*kcolumns+j];

                }
            }

        }
    }

    clock_t end = clock();

    printf("Sequential runtime = %f\n", (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

And here is the parallel code for convolution:

```
int index1, index2, a, b,x,y;

for(int z = 0; z<rows*columns;++z)
    *(output_matrix + z) = 0;

clock_t begin = clock();
#pragma omp parallel
# pragma omp for private(x,y,a, b, index1, index2) 
for(int z=0;z<rows*columns;++z){
    x=z/columns;
    y=z%columns;
    for(int i=0;i<krows;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<kcolumns;++j){
            a=x+i-krows/2;  
            b=y+j-kcolumns/2;                   
            if(a<0)
                index1=rows+a;
            else if(a>rows-1)
                index1=a-rows;
            else 
                index1=a;

            if(b<0)
                index2=columns+b;
            else if(b>columns-1)
                index2=b-columns;
            else 
                index2=b;

            output_matrix[x*columns+y]+=input_matrix[index1*columns+index2]*kernel_matrix[i*kcolumns+j];

        }
    }
}

clock_t end = clock();
printf("Parallel runtime using OMP= %f\n", (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Comment: Don't spam tags!

Comment: Parallelisation does not guarantee less total runtime. In terms of total clock cycles a parallel version will always take more than a sequential version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry about the tag. I changed my code to use chrono and now everything seems to be ok. Any advice on making It more efficient?
Thanks.